# get_post_custom single array

Tags: php, custom-field

Is there a way to return single values only when I run

```
get_post_custom($post_id);
```

it seems that I'm receiving double array, even when there only one value for this meta_key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is what I've done to achieve this, it will return single dimension array when single results are found, and bi-dimensional array when multiple results are found

```
/*
 * Get post custom Single (in functions.php)
 */

function get_post_custom_single($post_id) {
  $metas = get_post_custom($post_id);

  foreach($metas as $key => $value) {
    if(sizeof($value) == 1) {
      $metas[$key] = $value[0];
    }
  }
  return $metas;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// change the meta key and note the last true
get_post_meta($post_id, 'your_meta_key_goes_here', true);
```

See [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) for `get_post_meta`

If you look at `get_post_custom` in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) you will read:

> Returns a **multidimensional** array with all custom fields of a
>   particular post or page